# Razor Ошибка CS0103 Имя "ViewBag" не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, razor

[image: VS показывает ошибки на ключевых словах разметки Razor]

Как решить эту проблему?
Код переписывал с 0. вставлял. перезапускал студию
результат один:

> Ошибка    CS0103  Имя "model" не существует в текущем контексте.  SportsStore.WebUI   d:\programming\web\mvc_learn\sportsstore\sportsstore.webui\views\product\list.cshtml    2
>   Ошибка  CS0103  Имя "ViewBag" не существует в текущем контексте.    SportsStore.WebUI   d:\programming\web\mvc_learn\sportsstore\sportsstore.webui\views\product\list.cshtml    5

Представление генерировалось стандартными средствами студии путём вызова меню "добавить представление" на соотв. методе контроллера

Comment: При публикации проверь валидацию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В подобных случаях нужно проверять `web.config` и секцию razor'а, что-то там у вас неправильно написано.

Конкретно ваш случай пока не добавите свой `web.config` ничего конкретно будет сказать нельзя, только кидать ссылки на похожие случаи.

[Вот например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526437/mvc-3-project-rejects-requests-for-razor-views-with-cs0103-the-name-model-doe), кто-то удалил строчку нечаянно (просто для ознакомления, т.к. вопрос про старую версию asp.net mvc)

[Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346127/asp-net-error-cs0103-the-name-webmail-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) namespace отсутствовал.

Для начала я бы на вашем месте создал бы с нуля проект и сравнивал бы различия в настройках razor пытаясь понять, не сломалось ли чего.

Если не поможет -- то нужно ещё много чего проверять, но для этого нужно видеть проект, его структуру, по короткому фрагменту представления. Я по крайней мере ванговать не возьмусь, как у вас устроен Domain/DAL.